# Redis caching structure

Tags: caching, data-structures, redis

We are planning to use Redis as a cache at API end. I have particular scenario  as per requirements

1. Saving the meeting done by the users
2. We are already maintaining a list of UserId against the ClientID-- which 
        represent that user has access of that client

   **A meeting object has following attributes/properties

   1. MeetingId
   2. MeetingType
   3. MeetingDate
   4. ClientId
   5. MeetingStatus**

   As we are facing performance issue while getting the list of meeting from SQL DB, we planned to cache it using Redis. and we will be filtering the meeting from cache on following attributes/ property

   1> MeetingType (Call, Personal Visit)
   2> Meeting Status (Open, Closed) ... etc

   As of now we have finalized following approach

   Maintain a key for each filter

   1> MeetingType
              a> `Meeting:Call`, 
              b> `Meeting:PersonalVisit`

   2> Meeting Status 
               a>`MeetingStatus:Open`
               b>`MeetingStatus:Closed`

   And use key's interaction to filter data for

find all open meetings which the users had done by personal visit

Or is there's a better approach considering the below pain points

```
 1. How do I filter     the meeting of only clients of which he/she has
    access of.
 2. How do I achieve dynamic order by on MeetingId/MeetingStatus/....
    etc

Can you guide me where should I be heading for the above implementation
```

+ Would appreciate if you can share some good resource/links for redis

Comment: 1. How do I filter     the meeting of only clients of which he/she has
    access of.
 2. How do I achieve dynamic order by on MeetingId/MeetingStatus/....
    etc

Answer (score 0):

Redis is not made for querying as you do to relational databases. But as i've understood the problem. You've to optimise/tune your database settings. If problem still prevails then go for some NOSQL db. 
In redis, you can use a "hack". You can maintain hashmap of meetings for different filters.
i.e one for Meeting:Call, one for Meeting:PersonalVisit, one for MeetingStatus:Open, one for MeetingStatus:Closed etc

**Examples of Hash**

```
meeting_call [ 1:{meeting_obj1},4:{meeting_obj4} ] // redis hash for 
Meeting:Call filter
meetingstatus_open [ 5:{meeting_obj5},4:{meeting_obj4} ] // redis hash 
MeetingStatus:Open
```

You can above approach if your filters are very less, in short I'm storing  meetings after filtering.

Comment: I have already achieved this ie filtering meeting based on status and meetingtype by using intersection on sets but the issue I'm facing is, post the above mentioned filters I get the list of meetingids from intersecting the sets but I have to even filter meetings on clientid too. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: I have, What I'm asking is I want to filter meeting on two attribute  say meeting status and type ie open or close  and Call/PV ( this is done using set intersections ) but how do I filter on ClientId, Is it possible or not